# Unable to start windows service on a local machine(having windows xp)

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-xp

I have installed a windows service(C#) on my local machine having windows XP installed in it.

But when I tried to start that service It gave me this error-

The MyWindowsService service on Local Computer has started and then stopped. Some Services stops automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the performance logs and Alert Service.

Do you have any idea why this service isn't started?

Regards,

nzahra

Comment: You need to provide more information: what happens in Main, what happens in OnStart ?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` call at the start of your `Main()` method.  Then you can step through your service to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the account this service is running under. The user account should have enough privileges to be able to logon on as a service. [This link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r3m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sysadmin.hlp/msr10034.htm) may help out as well.

Comment: Wouldn't you get an error in event log if that was the problem?

Comment: Yes you would get an entry in event log.